# Identify salesforce schema changes

Tags: soap-api, metadata, bulk-api

I am backing up Account, Leads, Opportunities and Document objects. Initial level backup is full where I download using BULK API and then incremental subsequently. If there is a change in the schema level with any of the objects (field addition/deletion), how can I keep track of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Field level changes can be tracked only through metadata API. You can export it using force.com migration tool. If you are looking for the data in those new fields, you will have to update query each time before exporting data.

Comment: Apologies for the really delayed response. I am currently writing the `describeSObject()` call to XML for individual objects. This gives more flexibility in comparing individual XML fields and their types. If your solution deals with the Metadata API , by comparing the .objects files that would be giving out the details about the fields addition/deletion but would not give any other info about the field types. Am I right to compare with describeSObjects() call?